# Где находится программы и компоненты в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В windows можно было удалить любое приложение через вкладку "программы и компоненты". Где она находится в ubuntu

Comment: В Центре приложений (Software Center)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список установленных пакетов можно просмотреть с помощью команды :
`dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`

Можно также убрать всю лишнюю информацию и сохранить только имена пакетов:
`dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '{ print $2}'`

Такая команда отобразит все установленные пакеты вместе с информацией о них:
`dpkg-query -l`

Также можно использовать:
`apt list --installed`

Еще одна интересная возможность apt - посмотреть какие пакеты были установлены вручную:
`apt-mark showmanual`

И еще один вариант с использованием apt:
`apt-cache pkgnames`

Утилита для управления пакетами `aptitude` тоже позволяет вывести список установленных пакетов